# Constructing Rules in Rules Engine as Developer

Tags: oracle, rule-engine, peoplesoft

I need help below regarding Rules Engine Peoplesoft.

Given the needed data to create in Rules Engine Manager such as skill = developer.

And as stated here:

*Depending on user security as set up in Rule Category Security, the Rules Engine Manager can be accessed using different Skill Levels. Skill Levels that can be selected are Expert or Developer, with Developer having ability to create Rules where the logic is defined in Application Class PeopleCode. Experts create Rule logic in the Rules Engine Manager Define Rule Page.*

How do you create Rules where the logic is defined in Application Class PeopleCode?

Sorry I'm new to Rules Engine so I'm not that knowledgeable with its set-up and configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done it but assume you would use Application Designer to create a new application class that inherits from the correct class or implements the correct interface, or modify an existing application class.  You would need a PeopleCode developer to make these changes.

Answer (score 0):

I am also exploring the use of a rules engine in developer mode and it is shocking how little information is available on this. My colleague, however, was able to figure out the simplest structure required for the application class as pointed out Darryls99. Here is the structure:

```
import SCC_COMMON:ENTITY:GenericParentEntity;
import SCC_RULES_ENGINE:Util:RuleAbstract;
import SCC_RULES_ENGINE:Util:RuleFactory;
import SCC_RULES_ENGINE:Util:RuleInterface;

class YourClassName extends SCC_RULES_ENGINE:Util:RuleAbstract;

   property string YourVariable;
   method Query();
   method Run();

end-class;

method Query
   /+ Extends/implements SCC_RULES_ENGINE:Util:RuleAbstract.Query +/
   //Not sure what is suppose to happen here, we left it blank
end-method;

method Run
   /+ Extends/implements SCC_RULES_ENGINE:Util:RuleAbstract.Run +/
   //Here we put all our processing that was required

end-method;
```

If anybody could add more information it would be wonderful.